# Excel available resources

Tags: excel

So in the last week Excel (2010) has started coming up with this error message when I select the entire file using the arrow in the top left hand corner of the sheet: "Excel cannot complete this task with available resources.  Choose less data or close other applications."

But if I just select the columns it will sort.   it's only when using the select all button in the top left corner.

None of my memory usage seems outrageous on my machine.   I have closed all other programs and just used excel, but no dice.

Any bright ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Is the formatting on everything uniform or at least somewhat uniform? Sometimes if i have different elements in bold or with a solid background etc that gives me issues from time to time...

Comment: Pretty close.   Everything is set for General, with the exception being a date field

Comment: Hmmm..., looks like the MSFT Knowledge base has something on this however: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2655178/ Hopefully you haven't already visited that article...